# Error "nvcc cannot find a supported cl version" when compiling CUDA 5 with VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/devinmotion/CUDA_playground/wiki/Get-CUDA-5.0-working-with-Visual-Studio-2012) to compile cuda 5 with visual studio 2012 but I'm still receiving this:

```
nvcc : fatal error : nvcc cannot find a supported cl version. Only MSVC 9.0 and MSVC 10.0 are supported
```

What could cause this problem?

Comment: One of the descriptions linked from that site is [this one](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CUDA-50-and-Visual-Studio-20e71aa1).  Did you follow the instruction there to update the props file?  "cuda 5.0.props file  --  Add the following CudaClVersion where 2010 (not 2012) is not a mistake. CUDA will not work if you specify 2012 version.
 
 
 
<CudaClVersion Condition="'$(PlatformToolset)' == 'v110'">2010</CudaClVersion> "

Comment: Yes I did it, unfortunately that still doesn't work. I think that nvcc doesn't support dynamic parallelism yet also with that hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that if your code is using dynamic parallelism you need to use msvc2010

Answer (score 0):

At lest for me, the Corvella's [answer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CUDA-50-and-Visual-Studio-20e71aa1) worked, I built OpenCV 2.4.5(from OpenCV official site) and then Emgu(from Emgu git with OpenCV 2.4.9) with VS2012 and CUDA support, both were successful. I used Windows 7 64 and Windows 8 64. The error occurs when you missed "Build Customization" for some .cu files. Even though, it is just the beginning, you will meet many other errors. Good luck!